# Ignite not throwing exception on Ignition.getOrStart

Tags: ignite

I have 1 server and 1 client node. Both have same instance name and consistentId.
I have started server node and then client node.
On Ignition.getOrStart for client node I expect exception but it doesn't throw any exception. I tried with start also but it doesn't throw exception.

Can anyone please tell me correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug. Can you file an issue against [Apache Ignite JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE)?

Comment: I am using 2.8.1. If i starts 2 server nodes with same name and consistentId  Ignition.getOrStart throws exception. Issue is with different types on nodes.

Comment: I have filed a ticket: [IGNITE-13474](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-13474)